# Clarification in deleting a specific link from Doubly Linked List implementation in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I was writing an implementation of a doubly linked list in java, according to the book I'm reading. While I've got the logic pretty good so far, I had two questions which the book does not cover. My doubt is in the method which deletes a specific link(node) from the list[whose data (`int`) field matches the key passed in to the  method].

My questions are:

1. When the link to be deleted turns out to be the `first` link in the list, why isn't the `next` node's `previous` field being set to `null`, as the `next` node will now be the first node in the link, and therefore will not refer to anything through `previous`? What I mean is: `current.next.previous = null`
2. Similarly, when the link to be deleted is the `last` one in the link, why isn't the `previous` node's `next` link set to `null`? This new node will be the last in the list, so obviously it won't refer to any other link through `next`. I mean: `current.previous.next = null`

Here's my complete implementation, please excuse the abundant comments,I just like to keep track of what I'm doing.

```
package Chap_5;

/**
 * Created by Manish on 10/25/2015.
 * this is an implementation of a doubly linked list, it differs from a singly linked list in that you can traverse
 * backwards along the list. For this, every Link(node) in the list has a reference to the previous link called previous
 * Insertion routine has 3 methods - insertFirst(), insertLast() and insertAfter() which allows you to insert a node
 * at the beginning, at the end or after a specific item in the list
 * Deletion routine has 3 methods - deleteFirst(), deleteLast() and deleteKey(). the deleteKey() method allows to look
 * up a specific node and then delete it.
 * this doubly linked list is also a double ended list in that it always keeps a reference to the last node in the list
 * (along with the firs)
 */

class Link3 {

    //fields - int and 2 references to next and previous
    public int iData;
    public Link3 next;
    public Link3 previous;

    //constructor - initialize data and references are set to null auto.
    public Link3(int data) {
        iData = data;
    }

    //display the current link's data
    public void displayLink() {
        System.out.print("{" + iData + "} ");
    }
}

class DoublyLinkedList {

    //store 2 refernces to first and last link in list;
    private Link3 first;
    private Link3 last;

    //constructor to set references to null
    public DoublyLinkedList() {
        first = null;
        last = null;
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    //isEmpty() to check if list is empty
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (first == null);
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
        //----------------INSERTION ROUTINES--------------
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    //insertFirst() - to insert a node at the beginning of the list
    public void insertFirst(int data) {
        /**
         * inserts a link with given data at the front of the list
         */

        //create new link with data
        Link3 newLink = new Link3(data);

        //special case - if list is empty, set last accordingly
        if(isEmpty()) {
            last = newLink;
        }

        else {
            //else if list !empty, connect current first link's previous field to newlink
            first.previous = newLink;
        }

        //set next field of newlink to refer to old first
        newLink.next = first;
        //and set newlink as current first
        first = newLink;

    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    //method to insert at last of list
    public void insertLast(int data) {
        /**
         * inserts a link with given data at the end of linked list
         */

        //create new link with data
        Link3 newLink = new Link3(data);

        //special case - if list is empty
        if(isEmpty()) {
            first = newLink;
        }

        else {
            //if list not empty, make the current last's next refer to newlink
            last.next = newLink;
            //and set newlink's previous to current last
            newLink.previous = last;
        }

        //finally set last as newlink
        last = newLink;

    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    //method to insert at end of a specific link
    public boolean insertAfter(int key, int data) {
        /**
         * inserts a link with given data after the link whose data matches given key
         */

        //first search for link with given key, starting at beginning
        Link3 current = first;

        //until key with data is found
        while(current.iData != key) {
            current = current.next;

            //if end of list is reached without given key, exit
            if(current == null) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        //when link with key is found, create new link with data to be inserted after it
        Link3 newLink = new Link3(data);

        //if current link is the last one in the list
        if(current == last) {
            newLink.next = null;
            last = newLink;
        }

        //else if current link is not last one in the list
        else {

            //first modify the links towards the right

            //make the newlink's next field refer to current link's next field ie: following node
            newLink.next = current.next;
            //make the following node's previous field refer to newlink
            //NOTE: current.next.previous refers to the previous field of the link referred to by next field of the current link
            current.next.previous = newLink;
        }

        //then modify the links on the left
        //make newlink's previous field refer to current
        newLink.previous = current;
        //make current's next refer to newlink
        current.next = newLink;

        //return status of insertion
        return true;

    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
        //----------------DELETION ROUTINES--------------
    //------------------------------------------------------------------

    public Link3 deleteFirst() {
        /**
         * deletes first node from the linked list
         */
        //create link to be returned
        Link3 temp = first;

        //special case: if only 1 link in list
        if(first.next == null) {
            //set last as null as there will be no more links in list
            last = null;
        }
        //else if not just 1 link in next
        else {

            //set following node(after first)'s previous field to null as this will be the new first
            first.next.previous = null;
        }

        first = first.next;
        //and return deleted link
        return temp;

    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    public Link3 deleteLast() {
        /**
         * deletes last link from the linked list
         */

        //create link to be deleted
        Link3 temp = last;
        //special case - if only 1 link in list
        if(first.next == null) {
            //set first to null as no links in list anymore
            first = null;
        }

        else {
            //set current second last's next field to null as this is now the new last
            last.previous.next = null;
        }

        //and make the second last link as the new last
        last = last.previous;

        //and return deleted link
        return temp;

    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    public Link3 deleteKey(int key){
        /**
         * deletes link with given data, if found
         */

        //start searching for link from the first
        Link3 current = first;

        while (current.iData != key) {

            //move forward until link found
            current = current.next;

            if (current == null) {
                //if not found, return null
                return null;
            }
        }

        //when link found, adjust connections accordingly
        //special case 1 - if this is the first link
        if(current == first) {
            //set new first as the first's next link
            first = current.next;

        }
        else {
            //if this is not the first link
            // set preceeding link's next to refer to following link by current's next
            current.previous.next = current.next;
        }

        //special case 2 - if this is the last link
        if(current == last) {
            //set new last as the current last's previous link
            last = current.previous;
        }

        else {
            //set current link's next link's previous field to refer to current link's preceeding link
            current.next.previous = current.previous;
        }

        return current;
        }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
        //----------TRAVERSAL ROUTINES----------
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void displayForward() {
        /**
         * display links forward ie: left -> right
         */
        System.out.println("List (first -> last)");

        //start at first and move forward
        Link3 current = first;

        while (current != null) {
            current.displayLink();
            //change current to refer to following node
            current = current.next;
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void displayBackward() {
        /**
         * display links backward ie: right -> left
         */

        System.out.println("List (last -> first)");

        //start at last and move backward
        Link3 current = last;
        while (current != null) {
            current.displayLink();
            //change current to refer to previous node
            current = current.previous;
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}

public class DoublyLinkedApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //create new list
        DoublyLinkedList theList = new DoublyLinkedList();

        //insert 3 at front
        theList.insertFirst(22);
        theList.insertFirst(44);
        theList.insertFirst(66);

        //insert 3 items at end
        theList.insertLast(11);
        theList.insertLast(33);
        theList.insertLast(55);

        //display list forward
        theList.displayForward();

        //display list backward
        theList.displayBackward();

        //delete first item
        System.out.println("Deleted: " + theList.deleteFirst().iData);

        //delete last item
        System.out.println("Deleted: " + theList.deleteLast().iData);

        //delete a specific link - with key 11
        System.out.println("Deleted: " + theList.deleteKey(11).iData);

        //display list forward again
        theList.displayForward();

        //insert 2 items after a specific link
        //insert after link with data 22
        theList.insertAfter(22, 77);

        theList.displayForward();

        //insert after link with 33
        theList.insertAfter(33, 89);

        theList.displayForward();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the link to be deleted turns out to be the first link in the list, why isn't the next node's previous field being set to null

It is set to null by this instruction:

```
current.next.previous = current.previous;
```

Indeed, if current is the first node, `current.previous` is null, and the next node's previous is thus set to null by being set to `current.previous`.

The same goes for the last node's next, which is set to null by

```
current.previous.next = current.next;
```